# How to know that FB API call is finished?

Tags: facebook, api

I am in a bit problem right now. The scenario is, i take pageids of which i am an admin of using FQL. After getting the page ids, i want to to loop through those ids and call the below function:

```
FB.api('/'+id+'/tabs?fields=image_url,name,application', function(response) {
// Other stuff here
});
```

And from this i take the tab ids of every page and other details.

The issue is i dont get to know if the requests for every page id to get tabs is over. I have to manually set something like this:

```
setTimeout(loadAllNow, 5000);
```

assuming that the request for all pages is done in the time i waited before calling next function.

Is there any way i can get to know if the loop is over with all API calls returned me the desired result. Because while calling the api in a for loop, it just send all the API calls almost together and dont wait for the previous to get over.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can check manually like this-

```
pagesCount = NO_OF_PAGES;

FB.api('/'+id+'/tabs?fields=image_url,name,application', function(response) {

      count++;                // initialize this count to 0 before starting the loop
      if(count == pagesCount) // this is the final response
      {
          // Other stuff here 
      }
});
```

Comment: What is 'NO_OF_PAGES' ?